# perf annotated assembly seems off

Tags: c++, c++11, x86, perf

I want to measure the amount of time a C++ atomic fetch_add takes on different settings.  I wrote something like this:

```
atomic<uint64_t> x(0);
for (uint64_t i = 0; i < REPS; i+=1g) {
  x.fetch_add(1);
}
```

So that if `REPS` is high enough, I assume will be able to average the the `fetch_add` per second happening. First, I needed to validate most of the time was indeed spent within fetch_add, as opposed to loop overhead, for example.  So I ran perf to do this.

This is the assembly from objdump:

```
400ed0:       b8 00 b4 c4 04          mov    $0x4c4b400,%eax
400ed5:       0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
400ed8:       f0 83 05 7c 22 20 00    lock addl $0x1,0x20227c(%rip)
400edf:       01 
400ee0:       83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
400ee3:       75 f3                   jne    400ed8 <_Z10incrsharedv+0x8>
```

perf  (for the cycles event) says 100% of the cycles go into `sub    $0x1,%eax`, as opposed to what I would expect, `lock addl $0x1,0x20227c(%rip)` or the jump.  Any ideas why? is this accurate, or is it just a measurement artifact? In the second case, why would perf systematically attribute the latency to the `sub` line rather than to `addl`?

Comment: One question at a time please?

Comment: Good suggestion. I've removed the secondary question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** try using  the `:pp` suffix, for some events the processor can help give you more accurate annotation data.

Longer version:

In trying to investigate the behavior I described, I also attempted to use the following more unrolled loop. I think it solves the question to some extent.

```
  for (uint64_t i = 0; i < REPS; i+=10) {

    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);

    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
    x.fetch_add(1, ORDER);
  }
```

When using `perf record -e cycles`

The resulting perf annotate is:

```
      :      0000000000400f00 <incr(std::atomic<unsigned long>&)>:
 0.00 :        400f00:       mov    $0x3d0900,%eax
 0.00 :        400f05:       nopl   (%rax)
 0.00 :        400f08:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.93 :        400f0d:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.77 :        400f12:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.22 :        400f17:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 8.97 :        400f1c:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.39 :        400f21:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.87 :        400f26:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.48 :        400f2b:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.70 :        400f30:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.19 :        400f35:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.49 :        400f3a:       sub    $0x1,%rax
 0.00 :        400f3e:       jne
```

When I change the number of calls to fetch add to 5, there are 5 hotspots identified. This result suggests there is a systematic off-by-one instruction error in attributing the cycles in this case:

The perf wiki includes the following [warning](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sampling_with_perf_record):

"Interrupt-based sampling introduces skids on modern processors. That means that the instruction pointer stored in each sample designates the place where the program was interrupted to process the PMU interrupt, not the place where the counter actually overflows"

"the distance between those two points may be several dozen instructions or more if there were taken branches."

So, it looks like I should consider myself lucky for the annotation being off by one ;).

**Update:**  intel processors have support for a feature called PEBS (precise event based sampling), that makes correlating an instruction pointer to a counter event a lot less error prone  [See this forum post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/277553).

You can access this feature via `perf`as well, for selected counters:

Using `perf record -e cycles:pp` instead (notice the `:pp` suffix) the output from annotate this time is:

```
      :      0000000000400f00 <incr(std::atomic<unsigned long>&)>:
 0.00 :        400f00:       mov    $0x3d0900,%eax
 0.00 :        400f05:       nopl   (%rax)
10.75 :        400f08:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.15 :        400f0d:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.00 :        400f12:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.22 :        400f17:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.21 :        400f1c:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.75 :        400f21:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.95 :        400f26:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.02 :        400f2b:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
10.18 :        400f30:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 9.75 :        400f35:       lock addq $0x1,(%rdi)
 0.00 :        400f3a:       sub    $0x1,%rax
 0.00 :        400f3e:       jne    400f08
```

Which confirms the hunch. This is a solution that may be helpful in much trickier situations with jumps.

Comment: That makes sense. perf works by checking the instruction pointer on a timer interrupt. The interrupt is handled after the instruction it is triggered during, so if the fetch_add is taking most of the time there is a high probability for the instruction pointer to be immediately after it in the timer handler.

Comment: interesting. do you have a pointer to where to learn more about perf insides?

Comment: My comment was just based on knowledge of how processors handle interrupts, but the [perf wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Event-based_sampling_overview) mentions that it could actually be much further away and has lots of other information.